# Flutter Saving button state on device

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a search screen where users can search for a county and a list of vaccination posts in said county is shown. Some counties have many some have very few.

In the list of vaccination posts, there is a button that when pressed, the button is disabled. All is good until here, but when I re-search the same county, the button that was once disabled is no longer disabled, meaning it can be pressed again. I would like to avoid that.

I have a list of bools, "true" for each vaccination post. When button is pressed, respective index in the list is changed to "false" thus disabling the button.

Question: How can I keep the button disable? (Whether the same county is re-searched or the app is re-opened)

```
import 'package:colour/colour.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
// import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class VaccineCenterList extends StatefulWidget {
  const VaccineCenterList({key}) : super(key: key);
  static const String idScreen = "VaccineCenterList";

  @override
  _VaccineCenterListState createState() => _VaccineCenterListState();
}

class _VaccineCenterListState extends State<VaccineCenterList> {
  TextEditingController hospitalCountyEditingController =
      TextEditingController();
  final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  List<Hospitals> driverList = [];

  List<bool> buttonPressed = [];
  // Map<String, List> buttonPressed = {};

  buttonControls(numOfLocations) {
    print(numOfLocations);
    int checker = 0;
    if (numOfLocations > buttonPressed.length) {
      try {
        while (numOfLocations >= checker) {
          buttonPressed.add(true);
          checker = checker + 1;
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print("$e");
      }
    } else {}
    print(buttonPressed);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("I'm in the vaccine list search screen");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        title: Text(
          "Pamoja",
          style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 35,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
        },
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                // textfield
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: hospitalCountyEditingController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        style: BorderStyle.solid,
                        width: 1,
                      ),
                    ),
                    labelText: "Search County",
                    labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14.0,
                      color: Colors.blueGrey,
                    ),
                    hintStyle: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      fontSize: 10,
                    ),
                  ),
                  style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(
                    fontSize: 14,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                // search button
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(
                      FocusNode(),
                    );
                    driverList.clear();
                    if (hospitalCountyEditingController.text == "" ||
                        hospitalCountyEditingController.text == " ") {
                      isTrueOrFalse = "False";
                    } else {
                      isTrueOrFalse = "True";
                    }
                  });
                  getHospitalDetails();
                },
                child: Text(
                  "Search",
                  style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                      // height: 50,

                      // color: Colors.black,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          right: 12.0,
                          left: 12.0,
                          bottom: 12.0,
                        ),
                        child: driverList.isEmpty
                            ? Center(
                                // child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                child: (isTrueOrFalse == "True")
                                    ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
                                    : Column(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                        children: [
                                          Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                            child: Text(
                                                "Search for one of the counties below",
                                                style:
                                                    GoogleFonts.lexendMega()),
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            "Nairobi, Baringo, Busia, Bomet, Bungoma, Elgeyo Marakwet, Embu, Garissa, Homa Bay, Isiolo, Kajiado, Kakamega, Kericho, Kiambu, Kilifi, Kirinyaga, Kisii, Kisumu, Kitui, Kwale, Laikipia, Lamu, Machakos, Makueni, Mandera, Marsabit, Meru, Migori, Mombasa, Muranga, Nakuru, Nandi, Narok, Nyamira, Nyandarua, Nyeri, Samburu, Siaya County, Taita Taveta, Tana River County, Tharaka Nithi, Trans Nzoia, Turkana, Uasin Gishu, Vihiga, Wajir, West Pokot",
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                            style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                              )
                            : ListView.builder(
                                itemCount: driverList.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  final Hospitals hospitals = driverList[index];
                                  final String hospitalLocaiton =
                                      hospitals.location;
                                  final String hospitalPhone = hospitals.phone;
                                  final String hospitalName = hospitals.name;

                                  positiveCount = hospitals.positiveCount;
                                  negativeCount = hospitals.negativeCount;

                                  final int setpercentage =
                                      calculatePositivePercentage(
                                          positiveCount, negativeCount);

                                  buttonControls(driverList.length);

                                  return Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Card(
                                      elevation: 0,
                                      child: ExpansionTile(
                                        title: Text(
                                          hospitalName.toUpperCase(),
                                          style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(),
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        ),
                                        children: [
                                          Column(
                                            children: [
                                              Container(
                                                child: (hospitalPhone
                                                        .isNotEmpty)
                                                    ? ElevatedButton(
                                                        onPressed: () {
                                                          Clipboard.setData(
                                                            ClipboardData(
                                                              text:
                                                                  hospitalPhone,
                                                            ),
                                                          );
                                                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(
                                                                  context)
                                                              .showSnackBar(
                                                            const SnackBar(
                                                              backgroundColor:
                                                                  Colors.green,
                                                              content: Text(
                                                                "Number Copied",
                                                                textAlign:
                                                                    TextAlign
                                                                        .center,
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                          );
                                                        },
                                                        child: Text(
                                                          hospitalPhone,
                                                          textAlign:
                                                              TextAlign.center,
                                                          style: GoogleFonts
                                                              .lexendMega(
                                                                  fontSize: 13),
                                                        ),
                                                        style: ElevatedButton
                                                            .styleFrom(
                                                          elevation: 0,
                                                        ),
                                                      )
                                                    : const Text(""),
                                              ),
                                              const SizedBox(
                                                height: 5,
                                              ),
                                              hospitalLocaiton.isNotEmpty
                                                  ? Container(
                                                      padding:
                                                          const EdgeInsets.all(
                                                              8),
                                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                        border: Border.all(
                                                          color: Colors.black,
                                                        ),
                                                        borderRadius:
                                                            BorderRadius
                                                                .circular(10),
                                                      ),
                                                      child: Text(
                                                        hospitalLocaiton,
                                                        textAlign:
                                                            TextAlign.center,
                                                        style: GoogleFonts
                                                            .lexendMega(
                                                          fontSize: 12,
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    )
                                                  : Text(
                                                      hospitalLocaiton,
                                                      textAlign:
                                                          TextAlign.center,
                                                      style: GoogleFonts
                                                          .lexendMega(
                                                        fontSize: 12,
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                              const SizedBox(
                                                height: 10,
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                "$setpercentage% (percent) of voters say this hospital administer vaccines.",
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                  fontSize: 12,
                                                  color: Colors.deepPurple[400],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              const SizedBox(
                                                height: 10,
                                              ),
                                              const Divider(
                                                // thickness: 1,
                                                indent: 20,
                                                endIndent: 20,
                                                color: Colors.black87,
                                              ),
                                              const SizedBox(
                                                height: 10,
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                "Does this Hospital administer Vaccines?\n(To help the public, please vote only if you know.)",
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(
                                                  fontSize: 12,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              Column(
                                                children: [
                                                  Row(
                                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                                        MainAxisAlignment
                                                            .spaceEvenly,
                                                    children: [
                                                      ElevatedButton(
                                                        onPressed:
                                                            buttonPressed[index]
                                                                ? () {
                                                                    positiveIncrement(
                                                                        hospitalName,
                                                                        index);
                                                                    buttonPressed[
                                                                            index] =
                                                                        false;
                                                                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(
                                                                            context)
                                                                        .showSnackBar(
                                                                      const SnackBar(
                                                                        backgroundColor:
                                                                            Colors.redAccent,
                                                                        content:
                                                                            Text(
                                                                          "Voted",
                                                                          textAlign:
                                                                              TextAlign.center,
                                                                        ),
                                                                      ),
                                                                    );
                                                                  }
                                                                : null,
                                                        child: Text(
                                                          "Yes",
                                                          style: GoogleFonts
                                                              .lexendMega(),
                                                        ),
                                                        style: ElevatedButton
                                                            .styleFrom(
                                                          primary:
                                                              Colour("#87D68D"),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                      ElevatedButton(
                                                        onPressed:
                                                            buttonPressed[index]
                                                                ? () {
                                                                    negativeIncrement(
                                                                        hospitalName,
                                                                        index);
                                                                    buttonPressed[
                                                                            index] =
                                                                        false;
                                                                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(
                                                                            context)
                                                                        .showSnackBar(
                                                                      const SnackBar(
                                                                        backgroundColor:
                                                                            Colors.redAccent,
                                                                        content:
                                                                            Text(
                                                                          "Voted",
                                                                          textAlign:
                                                                              TextAlign.center,
                                                                        ),
                                                                      ),
                                                                    );
                                                                  }
                                                                : null,
                                                        child: Text(
                                                          "No",
                                                          style: GoogleFonts
                                                              .lexendMega(),
                                                        ),
                                                        style: ElevatedButton
                                                            .styleFrom(
                                                          primary:
                                                              Colour("#E3655B"),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                  const SizedBox(
                                                    height: 10,
                                                  ),
                                                  Text(
                                                    "1 - To vote, tap once\n2 - To Undo vote, tap and hold",
                                                    style:
                                                        GoogleFonts.lexendMega(
                                                      fontSize: 12,
                                                    ),
                                                    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                                  ),
                                                  const SizedBox(
                                                    height: 10,
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    // SizedBox(height: 40),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Hospitals {
  final String name;
  final String phone;
  final String location;
  // final String county;
  final int positiveCount;
  final int negativeCount;
  // final int intPercentage;
  // final int totalVotes;

  Hospitals({
    required this.name,
    required this.phone,
    required this.location,
    // required this.county,
    required this.positiveCount,
    required this.negativeCount,
    // required this.intPercentage,
    // required this.totalVotes,
  });

  static Hospitals fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Hospitals(
      name: json['HospitalName'],
      phone: json['HospitalPhone'],
      // county: json['county'],
      location: json['HospitalAddres'],
      positiveCount: json['poitiveCount'],
      negativeCount: json['negativeCount'],
      // intPercentage: json['intPercentage'],
      // totalVotes: json['totalVotes']
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did that this way: use the `provider` to set value, make `boolean` value

```
 late bool isMyButtonEnabled;

//in initState

setState(() {
      isMyButtonEnabled=
          myProvider.checkIfButtonShouldBeEnabled(widget.Id);
    }

//in build

ElevatedButton(
                              child: Text('SUBMIT'),
                              onPressed: !isMyButtonEnabled
                                  ? null
                                  : () async => {
//some code

                                   }
```

this way your `boolean` will be saved and available everywhere in the app using the Provider package (there are other even more advanced analogs of Provider there that can be used as well)